# MySQL Union Statement not working, struggling to see why

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

I am trying to unite two tables with the UNION statement. I am matching the columns of both tables. I do not understand what this issue is.

No syntax error is given.

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
Table B1:

id   Date            DR_code      DR_code     CR     CR_code
ob3  2019-12-31      B1           20000       0   
*then all values in table B1*

Table B2:

id   Date            DR_code      DR_code     CR     CR_code
ob4  2019-12-31      B2           1000       0   
*then all values in table B2*
```

Thanks for any help

*MySQL ver 14.14 dist 5.7.23*

```
# for loop below creates strings: B1 and B2
for bank in Bank_Account_Code:
    with engine.connect() as con:
        con.execute('''
        SELECT id, Date, DR_code, DR, CR, CR_code FROM '''+bank+'''
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, Date, DR_code, DR, CR, CR_code FROM Opening_Balances
        WHERE DR_code="'''+bank+'''"
        ;''')
        con.execute('''
        SELECT id, Date, DR_code, DR, CR, CR_code FROM '''+bank+'''
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, Date, DR_code, DR, CR, CR_code FROM Opening_Balances
        WHERE CR_code="'''+bank+'''"
        ORDER BY DATE
        ;''')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Please add the expected result.

Comment: im sorry. Im on my ipad and cant copy and paste table data from bash. apologies

Comment: I have added the expected result

Comment: Not Working - in what way?

Comment: What fails? What result do you get with the code you show?

Comment: Thats the strange thing - no errors - it runs fine. just doesnt unite them

Comment: What is the value of bank in all 4 occurances in the code -